# Skilled Migrant - Expression Of Interest for New Zealand

Tags: new-zealand, skilled-migration, application-status

I was selected for New Zealand's "Skilled Migrant - Expression Of Interest" program on November 11th, 2022. However, after a few weeks, the status of my application changed back to "submitted", but there was a new field that said "date selected" and it showed the date I was selected.

What does this mean?

Comment: I would interpret it to mean your selection is registered in the system and the next step (submitting a visa application) is awaited.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Traveller